# Logging through configuration NPoco

Tags: oracle, logging, configuration, npoco

Several columns of a table are not being updated on our production environment, but are working properly on acceptance environment. They should be the same, especially when it comes to the database.

I'd like to investigate the error through logging.
Is there a way to enable that through configuration?

EntityFramework has [extensive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-desktop-optimization-pack/agpm/logging-and-tracing-settings) logging and tracing options.
But of course that's much more complicated, this may not be possible with a low footprint framework like NPoco.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an [Interceptor](https://github.com/schotime/NPoco/wiki/Version-3) to capture the command and details then log this. Previously you had to create a derived class from database and override various members.